# How do I customize or view all the available Substrate-Prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus, metrics, monitoring, alerts

I would like to view or define custom metrics on Substrate node.
Also, I would also like to access the alert rules as currently it returns [PAGE NOT FOUND:](https://%20https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/.maintain/monitoring/alerting-rules/alerting-rules.yaml)

Comment: I believe the resource you are looking for is now here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/scripts/ci/monitoring/alerting-rules/alerting-rules.yaml

Comment: Thank you for point me to the right resource @Bruno. One more question: I see bunch of metrics exported by substrate, is there a way of adding a custom metric or any link to all the metrics being exported by Substrate?

Comment: Please update the question to provide more detail: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask so others can also benefit from this post.

Comment: Substrate exports multiple Prometheus metrics which I was looking to find where if possible one can define own metrics to be exported. Now I am able to view all exported metrics but still not finding a way to define a custom metrics. I hope I clarified it enough?